# How to identify HL7 order request(ORM) message corresponding to response message(ORR)

Tags: hl7, medical, hl7-v2

I am into **HL7** parser development and still learning HL7. Read articles regarding Orders but still not clear about how to identify the HL7 order request corresponding to HL7 order response message.

**Additional Info:**
About 'MessageControlId' in MSH segment: The receiving system echoes 'MessageControlId'(10th field of **MSH** segment) back to the sending system in the Message acknowledgment segment(**MSA**). By using this ID we can identify the ACK corresponding to the request.
Need to confirm whether response message will also contain this message id.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide some sample ORM and corresponding ORR messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORM message type was deprecated in version 2.4 and withdrawn in 2.7 so you really shouldn't be using it at all any more. But if you do decide to use it, the matching ORM and ORR messages should have the same value in the ORC-2 (placer order number) field. Note that for a single real world order there may be multiple ORM and ORR messages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Nick, Can you able to provide some samples. Also what will be **type of response message** for ORM. (ORM for request , ORR for acknowledgment...)

Comment: You can find a partial ORM sample in the HL7 2.6 Standard section 4.6.1. https://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185

Comment: Indicating that this is a moot point since ORM is deprecated in later versions in 2.4 is not a safe assumption. Many EHR and LIS/RIS/*IS systems still run using HL7 v2.3, including Epic. ORMs are still very relevant as a day-to-day HL7 implementer.